# Javascript fetching text from textarea & posting to php page

Tags: javascript, php, html

I've got a textarea on a page used to submit posts, like in a chat or forum. To show how the posts are formatted I'm trying to get a preview function to work, using javascript. Once the preview-link is clicked, the script should fetch the text from the textarea (id = inputinsertcommentary) and post it to a popup window (postvorschau.php), where it's previewed using the $_POST variable.
Here's my script:

```
function postvorschau() {
    var url = 'www.page.com/folder/postvorschau.php';
    var form = document.createElement('form');
    form.action = url;
    form.method = 'POST';
    form.setAttribute("target", "_blank");

    var text = document.getElementById('inputinsertcommentary').value; 
    var postname ='posting';
        var input = document.createElement('input');
        input.type = 'hidden';
        input.name = postname;
        input.value = text;
        form.appendChild(input);
form.submit();
}
```

And here's the link where the function is called:

```
<a href='javascript: postvorschau();'>Postvorschau</a>
```

As far as I can see from my browser log (firefox), the function is called and doesn't produce any errors. However, there's no popup window opened - I suppose something in my syntax is wrong, but from looking at similar examples I can't really figure out what. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: does it submit the form?

Comment: The way your code looks at the moment the js function will submit the existing form to the url specified and you will not get the popup window ( I assume a div centred on screen like lightbox perhaps? ) - to do that you would need to send the content of the textarea to the php script using ajax and use the callback function to render the output in the popup

Comment: Where is the function post_to_url? Maybe you should use postvorschau() instead?

Comment: @RamRaider As far as I can tell it's not even submitted. So, essentially there's no way to get this function to work without ajax? The popup window would be another php file, where the received $_POST is formatted slightly different. (Some str_replaces, etc.) Thanks for your time!

Comment: @Nora , thanks for pointing that out - I had it right in the file, but when copying it over here I must have taken a earlier example. Edited in the first post, too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A basic example of using ajax to send the contents from the textarea to the backend script. The php script presumably formats the data and then prints it out.

```
<?php
    /* postvorschau.php: format data and send back to callback */
    if( !empty( $_POST ) ) {
        /* you would send back formatted data probably - whatever that might be */
        exit( json_encode( $_POST, true ) );
    }
?>

<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset='utf-8'>
        <title>html preview</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form>
            <textarea name='inputinsertcommentary' cols=80 rows=10 style='resize:none' placeholder='Enter comments / data here and use preview button / link'></textarea>
            <a href='#'>Preview</a>
        </form>
        <script>
            var olnk=document.querySelectorAll('form a')[0];
            olnk.onclick=preview;

            function preview(e){
                /* get textarea ~ you could use ids instead of course */
                var oTxt=e.target.parentNode.querySelectorAll('textarea')[0];
                /* create request object */
                var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
                xhr.onreadystatechange=function(){
                    /* invoke callback with response data */
                    if( xhr.readyState==4 && xhr.status==200 ) cbpreview.call( this, xhr.response );
                };

                xhr.open( 'POST', '/folder/postvorschau.php' );
                xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type','application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
                xhr.send( 'data='+oTxt.value ); 
            }

            function cbpreview(r){
                alert( r );/* use this callback to generate the "popup" using "r" as the data, either formatted or raw */
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Excellent answer - thank you for your time and annotations - this solved my issue and I gave me a better grasp on the underlying functions!